# variadic format strings in C macros?

Tags: c, macros, variadic-macros

I'm trying to write a basic macro like this:

```
#define USER_ERROR(fmt, ...) { \
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR %s(): %s\n", __func__, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
} \
```

my ideal usage:

```c
USER_ERROR("something went wrong %s %s", more_detail, even_more_detail);
```

unfortunately, I'm getting a compilation error:

> data argument not used by format string

I know that single `%s` handles one argument, but how can I make the formatter variadic?

Comment: You can't "nest" format specifiers: it isn't recursive. The string you supplied for `%s` can't itself contain format specifiers (that will be interpreted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string constant concatenation to combine your format string with the built-in one in your macro:

```
#define USER_ERROR(fmt, ...) \
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR %s(): " fmt "\n", __func__, ##__VA_ARGS__);

int main()
{
    char more_detail[]="abc", even_more_detail[]="def";
    USER_ERROR("something went wrong %s %s", more_detail, even_more_detail);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ERROR main(): something went wrong abc def
```

This also has the side effect of ensuring that your format string is a string constant, as having a format string potentially under the control of a user can lead to security issues.